# PhoneGap's OnDeviceReady is not firing on subsequent Blackberry pages

Tags: blackberry, cordova

My phonegap OnDeviceReady event is firing on the first page of my app, but doesn't fire when I go to the second page.  I am including sample code for both pages.  Note, that if I rename the second page to index.html, it will fire the OnDeviceReady, it just doesn't work if I navigate to the page through another page.

I am using the BlackBerry 9550 Emulator, and Phonegap 0.9.6

Here is the code for the first Page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
 </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scrollView;
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("OnDeviceReady");
    }
</script>
<script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body onload="onLoad()" background-color="white">
    <h1><a href="index2.html" >GoToIndex2</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my second Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scrollView;
function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("2: OnDeviceReady");
    }
</script>
<script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body onload="onLoad()" background="white">
<h1><a href="index.html" >GoToIndex 1</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work with the phonegap 1.0.0 code that was released today.

Comment: How did you solve it, I got 1.0.0 but still having the same problem....

Comment: @Tolbahady Are you able to get the sample to work? What I did, was after I had the sample working, I copied the index.html to index1.html and created a link from the original index.html to the index2.html, and the ondeviceready fired for both pages. After that, I copied my index and other another page over the index.html and index2.html and they worked too, once I replaced their headers with the header from PhoneGap's sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which BlackBerry OS are you using? The PhoneGap documentation for [deviceready](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready) points out that it doesn't work in 4.6 and suggests a workaround.

Comment: I was using 5.0.0.469.  The deviceready event would fire on the index, just not on a page that was a link from the index.  However, this seems to be fixed in the 1.0.0 version of phonegap, so I am no longer having this problem.

Comment: I missed the part of the documentation that stated that It wouldn't work with a 5.0 device.

Answer (score 0):

I took the sample from PhoneGap version 1.0.0, it was working fine till I added the sencha script file then it didn't work anymore

```
<script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="phonegap.1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="sencha.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```